# Como separar uma string quando a string não tem um separador?

Tags: java

Tenho uma String:

```
String texto = "1234";

String split[] = texto.split(?);
```

Preciso separar os caracteres, 1-2-3-4, sendo que cada número é 1 caractere somente.

Comment: O que você quer separar do que afinal?

Comment: Mateus, poderia explicar o porque você quer fazer isto ? isso ajudaria a resolver seu problema

Comment: Utilize chartAt ao inves de split

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Utilize split com expressão regular procurando por qualquer caracter. Segue exemplo abaixo

```
String texto = "1234";

String split[] = texto.split("(?!^)");
```

Resultado

```
split ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar o `split` com expressão regular como @Marquezani disse, e outra forma de fazer isso é usar o `toCharArray`. Veja:

```
String texto = "1234";
char[] numbers = texto.toCharArray();

// imprimindo primeiro caracter
System.out.print("Primeiro caracter: "+numbers[0]);
```

Resultado:

> Primeiro caracter: 1

Veja funcionando [no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/GZJ4LC).

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o método `charAt` para separar os números da string e um laço adicionando num novo array:

```
String texto = "1234";
String[] textoSeparado = new String[texto.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < textoSeparado.length; i++){
    textoSeparado[i] = "" + texto.charAt(i);
}
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/o1d222).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode realizar o `split` por "nenhum" caractere:

```
String texto = "1234";
String split[] = texto.split("");

// [0] = "1"
// [1] = "2"
// [2] = "3"
// [3] = "4"
```